# ZF Doctrine model class ext Base Class

Tags: php, zend-framework, model, doctrine

I am obviously in the deep end. I fail to grasp the benefit of Doctrine ModelClass and Model Table Class extending the Base Model

for example

```
class StaffStaff extends Base_StaffStaff
{
    public function getStaffInformation($id_staff_staff){   // == getInformationsByStaff()

        $query = Doctrine_Query::create()
                        ->from("StaffStaff s")
                        ->innerJoin('s.StaffContract c')
                        ->where("s.id_staff_staff = ?", $id_staff_staff);
        $result = $query->execute();

        return $result;

    }
}
```

and in the controller

```
StaffController{

    public function readAction() {

        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam("id_staff_staff");

        // Get information about a staff
        $model = new StaffStaff();
        $q = $model->getStaffInformation($id);

        $this->view->data = $q[0];

/**
*
* Why do you have to say $q[0] ?
* Is there no better way of doing it?
* How can we access the properties from other tables contained inside the BaseClass extended by the ModelClass
*
*/
}
```

Model:

```
/**
 * Base_StaffStaff
 * 
 * This class has been auto-generated by the Doctrine ORM Framework
 * 
 * @property integer $id_staff_staff
 * @property integer $fk_id_staff_individual
 * @property integer $fk_id_staff_team
 * @property integer $fk_id_staff_function
 * 
 */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the Query Builder API, which is how you assembled your query in the `getStaffInformation()` function, the `execute()` method returns an iterable cursor. This cursor is in essence an array, which is why $q[0] will access the first element.

If you instead are trying to only return one result, you should use `getSingleResult()` instead:

```
$query = Doctrine_Query::create()
   ->from("StaffStaff s")
   ->innerJoin('s.StaffContract c')
   ->where("s.id_staff_staff = ?", $id_staff_staff);
return $query->getSingleResult();
```

On the other hand the iterable cursor is neat to have because you can do something like:

```
$staff = $model->getStaffInformation($id);
foreach($staff as $person)
{
   // Assign all staff to view array
   $this->view->staff[] = $person;
}
```